# My VBA Vlookup is returning N/A. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: excel, vba

So I have a list that was pre-assembled and I'm attempting to now add more to the list from another workbook I have. I figured I could use VBA to create a macro to perform a VLookup to retrieve and populate the added fields.

My VBA:

```
Option Explicit
Sub CompareUntimed()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim utsheet As Worksheet
    Dim utlastrow, f9lastrow, J As Long
    Dim f9sheet As Worksheet
    Dim ctr As Integer
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(get_user_specified_filepath())
    Set utsheet = wb.Sheets(2)
    utlastrow = utsheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Set f9sheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Part List")
    f9lastrow = f9sheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For J = 2 To f9lastrow
        f9sheet.Range("G" & J) = Application.VLookup(f9sheet.Range("H" & f9lastrow), utsheet.Range("S2:S" & utlastrow), 17, False)
        f9sheet.Range("F" & J) = Application.VLookup(f9sheet.Range("H" & f9lastrow), utsheet.Range("S2:S" & utlastow), 10, False)
    Next J
End Sub
```

This is the Workbook where I'm getting #N/A instead of the proper values
[image]

This is the Workbook I'm attempting to match to and take values from
[image]

I'm attempting to use the UniqueID columns I've created which is the last column in each workbook and I'm attempting to add the dates and modified by columns to my new workbook.

Comment: You can't look up the 17th column of a single-column range!

Comment: And why isn't your look up range fixed?

Comment: You're not using `utlastrow`  Also there's no need for `On Error Resume Next` here

Comment: @SJR I fixed the Column Range so that its ```A2:S & lastrow``` I'm confused about what you mean that my lookup range isn't fixed? You mean why it isn't ```A2:S20``` as an example right?

Comment: Yes, when j=2 your range is one row deep. Is that intentional?

Comment: Yes, Row 1 is a header row and my range isn't fixed as the size of my sheets range depending on what is classified as what when the sheets are generated.

Comment: What I meant was that your range increases with the loop as it refers to `j`, which seems odd.

Comment: Ohhhhhh yeah, I just noticed that now that you mentioned it and that appears to be an oversite. That is why I wrote ```utlastrow```

Comment: @SJR I made changes to my code to fix those oddities.

Comment: Have you still got a problem?

Comment: @SJR Yes, It still returns N/A in all of the Cells..

Comment: Can't really tell from your pics what you're doing but check on the sheet to see it works there and for trailing/leading spaces.

Comment: @SJR I am attempting to find which rows between the two workbooks are the same piece and then i want to post the modified by and the valid from in the workbook w/ the macro

Comment: @SJR So in Macro Workbook I want Columns F  & G to be filled with matching entries from my other workbook's Columns R & K. Both Workbook have a column that has a ID which can be used to match rows. Which is Column H in my Macro Workbook and S in the other workbook

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub CompareUntimed()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim utsheet As Worksheet
    Dim utlastrow, f9lastrow, J As Long
    Dim f9sheet As Worksheet
    Dim ctr As Long

    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(get_user_specified_filepath())
    Set utsheet = wb.Sheets(2)

    Set f9sheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Part List")
    f9lastrow = f9sheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    For J = 2 To f9lastrow
        m = Application.Match(f9sheet.Range("H" & J), utsheet.Columns("S"), 0)
        If Not IsError(m) Then
            f9sheet.Range("G" & J).Value = utsheet.Cells(m, "K").Value
            f9sheet.Range("F" & J).Value = utsheet.Cells(m, "R").Value
        Else
            f9sheet.Range("F" & J).Resize(1,2).Value = "???"
        End If
    Next J
End Sub
```

Comment: Hey, Sorry about the late reply I haven't been able to work on this until now. This macro seems to just make everything a ??. I don't quite understand what the code is attempting with the matching command, If I am right its matching a value in f9sheet and utsheet and then if it matches it changes the values but I'm not entirely sure if I understand it

Comment: It's matching the value from Col H on f9sheet against Col S on utsheet. When there's no match then Application.Match returns an error value, which can be tested using IsError().   So you will see "??" when there's no match.

Comment: What could be causing something to not match, as I know there are matches between the sheets.

Comment: I can't really say what's going on without seeing your workbook. Either I'm using the wrong inputs or there's something weird in your data.

Comment: I posted photos of a few lines in my post above. Would those be any help?

Comment: I can't see which column is which on those screenshots ...  Can you share your workbook ?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't post it for privacy related reasons however you are correct that utsheet has the reference values in Col S and f9sheet has its references in Col H.

Comment: Can you update your screenshots so they show the column headers?

Comment: I've gone and updated the Screenshots so that they include the headers and column letters.

Comment: Thanks but I'm not seeing any matches there (I realize these are just samples) Seems like there's something else going on, but I'm unable to help without seeing your actual data.  If you want to xxxxx out all data apart from the columns to match on then there should be no problem sharing that.   Preferably just the two sheets and no VBA.

Comment: First, How would I go about sharing such a sheet? Second, The issue wit hblanking out the data is that the last columns on both sheets the ones that contain the UniqueIDs of each row is made up on a combination of the Part # and Operation # for that Row.

Comment: Also another question about the code you posted, Looking at the Match you have ```f9sheet.Range("F" & J).Value = utsheet.Cells(m, "R").Value``` Why have the m and then the Col? doesn't cells read whatever is in there as (Col,Row)?

Comment: I fixed it... I completely blanked out on how to use workbook.sheets.. I forgot that sheet objects start at base 1 not base 0. I apologize as soon as I fixed the sheet it worked..